# How to migrate data to from magento 1.9.1 to 2.0.4?

Tags: migration, magento-2.0.4

I have install magento 2.0.4 and now I want to migrate all database table, theme, content everything from old version 1.9.1 to this new one 2.0.4. I have gone through many articles saying that the database structure and themes are all different in 2.0.4 .Can anyone guide with steps on how can I successfully transfer all data to new version?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tool [magento2_data_migration](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration)
 made by `uber theme`.

**But keep in mind that it will help to migrate the data only.**

See more details [here](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/).

**Happy learning**

Comment: You can mark this as accepted for all community users

Comment: Hi can you explain me step 4 of uber theme. How should i run "php indexer.php reindexall" my site is not on xmap it is on server and I access using backend and cpanel. Then how will i give path and run this?

Comment: You need to have ssh for doing this

Comment: i have ssh shell access in cpanel

Comment: It has some manage ssh keys. i don't know how this works?

Comment: Hi, this helped me lot. I want to ask two things :1.) my products are not displaying on categories. everything is enable and  yes. 2.) extensions we have to install manually?

Comment: 1. Try to run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` 2. Yes you have to the structure also you have to convert all code as per magento2

Comment: Structure of? and what code?

Comment: Extensions structure and code?

Comment: yup!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So if i will install the latest version of extension or  magento connect2.0 that will not work?

Comment: Yes that will also work.. but if you can not found any latest version for that your need to convert all code and structure

Comment: ok you were very helpfull.. thank you so much :) just one more thing my products in dashboard is not showing images. i have copied catalog and downloadable folder and also on my category products are displaying but there images are not showing like a default magento logo is display and when i view product image displays but not on category and also in the dashboard when i edit product and go to images no images are seen.